# Усройство работа проца на низком уровне

Tags: процессор

Добрый день!

Подкиньте пожалуйста пару статей, где объясняют, как процессор обрабатывает команды на самом низком уровне, вот почему-то интересно стало.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Недавно как-то на [вопрос о истории программирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/404473/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=404591#404591) советовал почитать книгу Ч.Петцольда "Код. Тайный язык информации.", которая может прояснить простым языком принцип работы компьютера и многой электроники в целом. Прочитайте, не пожалеете об этом точно, на русском в сети есть.

Книга сравнительно не маленькая, но не думаю, что такую тему можно разжевать даже в 10-ке статей, да и информация очень разрозненная и некоторая не подъемная из-за отсутствия элементарных знаний, которые как мне кажется есть в этой книге. После нее можно и посложнее книги, статьи уже почитать о работе микропроцессоров и электроники.

Answer (score 2):

Можно почитать [тут](http://all-ht.ru/inf/pc/cp_struct.html), а если сложновато, то можно начать, например с [этого](http://sdelaycomputersam.ru/CPU.html).

Вообще же, на очевидный запрос

```
устройство cpu
```

гугл выдает кучу ссылок.